# Babel gives error "\bbl@pop@lang has an extra }"

Tags: tables, luatex, babel

There's a line in my CV document that's been there for years, but now it causes an error message. I've stripped it down to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main = american, ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    \begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}foo\end{otherlanguage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives the error `Argument of \bbl@pop@lang has an extra }`.

I'm running texlive 2020 in Windows with all packages updated today, and compiling with lualatex. It's clearly `babel` that causes the error, but this has always compiled fine before. It also compiles if the offending line is not in a tabular environment.

What's causing this error, and how can I fix it (and why has it compiled for years until now)?

Comment: well sometimes people introduce errors in the code. Open an issue at the babel issue tracker.

Comment: As someone who has introduced a fair bit of errors in code: Please, please, *please* report this to the developer via the bug report routes mentioned in the documentation. Even if it turns out that this was never officially supposed to work I cannot imagine a developer not wanting to know about these kind of things. And if it is indeed a bug, it is much, much better to have this reported officially in the right place for the developer to fix it than have a post like this rotting away in some online forum. Developers can only fix bugs they get to know about.

Comment: @moewe Fair enough, I should've realized this turned into a bug report and not a question about what was wrong with my code. I've submitted the report [here](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/93).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug report. The bug was reported and fixed in `babel` 3.48 (see link in comment above). The MWE compiles fine in new versions of `babel`.